# Unity not loading after uninstalling kubuntu

Tags: boot, unity, kubuntu

I installed kubuntu to see what its like, hated it and wanted to go back to unity. So i uninstalled it. The problem now is that I dont seem to get unity running. Booting always hangs at a list with green OKs, with Started Tell Plymouth to write out runtime data. Booting in any graphics mode does the same.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by deleting the config folder and then rebooting.

Comment: Which configuration folder did you delete and how? Ping me, if you want an up-vote on the improved answer. Also, please accept the answer that provides the best solution for the issue in your question, which seems to be your own answer in this case if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I sadly cannot remember, I think it was the lightdm config folder, but I dont want to give a inconclusive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall ubuntu-desktop again. Enter some tty (with ctrl+alt+F1) after boot or go to `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`->`Recovery mode`->`root` from the grub menu at boot (press and hold alt or space or esc or shift during boot if you don't see the grub menu) and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install -f #in order to fix any inconsistencies
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

*`ubuntu-desktop` will install more things than just unity that you have probably removed after installation but it's the safest way to make it working again*

Comment: Thanks for replying ! I managed to solve the issue by deleting the config folder, then rebooting. Xubuntu is now in all its glory functioning perfectly. :)

Comment: @RaduChirovici Aaaa ok, I ll delete my answer then. Mark this question as closed or answer it yourself and accept your answer.